# redmine + apache + mysql. ошибка при входе в настройки

Tags: mysql, apache, redmine, centos7

Поднял redmine через apche, база на mysql. ОС CentOS 7.
Вроде всё в порядке, но когда захожу в настройки то:

```
Errno::EACCES in Settings#index 

 Showing /var/www/redmine/www/app/views/settings/_display.html.erb where line #6 raised: 
Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /var/www/redmine/www/tmp/cache/D3D
 Extracted source (around line #125): 123
124
125
126
127
128
                          sort {|x,y| x.first  y.first }
      else
        ActionController::Base.cache_store.fetch "i18n/languages_options/#{Redmine::VERSION}" do
          languages_options :cache => false
        end
      end



Trace of template inclusion: app/views/common/_tabs.html.erb, app/views/settings/edit.html.erb

Rails.root: /var/www/redmine/www
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace 
lib/redmine/i18n.rb:125:in `languages_options'
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:1180:in `lang_options_for_select'
app/views/settings/_display.html.erb:6:in `block in _app_views_settings__display_html_erb__3459468401535038752_46941800744300'
app/views/settings/_display.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_settings__display_html_erb__3459468401535038752_46941800744300'
app/views/common/_tabs.html.erb:17:in `block in _app_views_common__tabs_html_erb__4571587298555466997_69888800216280'
app/views/common/_tabs.html.erb:16:in `each'
app/views/common/_tabs.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_common__tabs_html_erb__4571587298555466997_69888800216280'
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:345:in `render_tabs'
app/views/settings/edit.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_settings_edit_html_erb__2813292407351154857_69888799245500'
app/controllers/settings_controller.rb:31:in `index'
lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'
```

Не знаю как это нормально оформить. Приложу скриншот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю что проблема с языком, но не могу понять где именно.
Подскажите что не так.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался.
Надо было SELinux отключить.